# Different views on a single link in Quicklaunch

Tags: 2013, list-view, navigation, quick-launch

Good morning everyone!

I have a conception/ view issue

**What i have**

I have a Library, let's call it "MyLibrary".
For this library, I have defined different views. the default is as usual AllItems and i have InEnglish and InFrench.

In my navigation, for the Quicklaunch menu, i have set a link "MyLibrary" to /Site/MyLibrary/Forms/allitems.aspx.
When clicking on it, i see all my documents and the item in quicklaunch is set as "selected" and have a little arrow to show the user where he is.

So, the user can see the other views. When clicking on InEnglish, he got all documents in english. But in Quicklaunch, the Library is no longer selected.

A normal Behavior, because i've set the link to "allitems.aspx".

**What i want to achieve**

Now, I would like the "MyLibrary" link to be selected no matter the view i select.

**What i've tried**

- Setting the link "MyLibrary" to /Site/MyLibrary/Forms/
  *result* : no document is showing, and the selected item in QuickLaunch is the link to "Site"
- Setting the link "MyLibrary" to /Site/MyLibrary/ (because, basically, all the views belong to this library)
  *result* : the AllItems.aspx is displayed (with choice to InEnglish and InFrench views), **BUT** the selected item in QuickLaunch is the link to "Site"

**What i could do but CAN NOT because of specifications**

- Setting a link per view in QuickLaunch => too many links in the Quicklaunch, no longer user friendly, and too much time : because i have a lot of libraries/lists in this case and circa. 1200 subsites to modify

So, **do you have any idea on how to link the different views on ONE item of quicklaunch?**

Thanks a lot to help me think!

Answer (score 0):

You have well explained the situation but before purposing any solution it would be great if you share the problem with screenshots and flow. That would help a lot in understanding the scenario for all.

Probably you can have some custom script on the library allitems.aspx page.

Regards,